# Google.Apis.Blogger.v3 Nuget package not installing

Tags: c#, blogger, nuget-package

I am trying to install Google.Apis.Blogger.v3 in my c# console application.

But I am getting error as

> "'Google.Apis.Blogger.v3' could not be installed because it is not
>   compatible with any project in the solution. The package doesn't
>   target any framework. nuget package".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are talking about this package: [Google.Apis.Blogger.v3](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Blogger.v3/). As you can see, it supports the following platforms:

```
Supported Platforms:
- .NET Framework 4 and 4.5
- Windows Store apps
- Windows Phone 7.5 and 8
- Portable Class Libraries
```

I suppose your project is targeted to `.NET Framework 4 Client Profile`, which is by default. So, you should right-click your project in Solution Explorer, pick `Properties` and on `Application` tab choose `.NET Framework 4` (without `Client Profile`)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I just tried and it installed without any problems. Are you using the official nuget feed (https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/)?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with Google.apis.customsearch.  In Visual Studio 2010, I was finally able to install after several steps:

- Installed the Nuget package manager **update** (Tools > Extension Manager > Updates)
- Used the Nuget package manager console command `Install-Package Google.Apis.Customsearch.v1` from the [Nuget site](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Customsearch.v1/)